# Xbox one Game Updates Stuck

Tags: xbox-one

So I bought GTA V and I installed the game. Afterwards, I wanted to play but I was forced to update the game.

When I update the game, it is stuck at 0%, every time. I even left the game update overnight and it was still stuck. How can I get around this very annoying issue? I haven't had to update any other games so this is the first time this has happened to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you 100% sure your Xbox was connected to Internet at that time? Turn off the Xbox (completely, not stand-by mode) and try to restart the download.

Alternatively, you could try to delete the local files of GTA V, and then reinstall them. You'll have to redo the download but it should work this time.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I guess the xbox was disconnecting from the wifi!

Comment: Happy I could help! Happy gaming!